# The serverRuntime@appConcurrentRequestLimit setting is being exceeded

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012

I am asking a question on what is the way to fix this? when I visit my website I get this:

```
HTTP Error 503.2 - Service Unavailable
The serverRuntime@appConcurrentRequestLimit setting is being exceeded.
```

I use IIS on Windows Server 2012, and I have already set Concurrent requests to maximum value? I am pretty sure someone is spamming us with connections, how can this be fixed?